# How to use mongodb $setDifference on a query like this?

Tags: mongodb-query

As a mongodb newbie I can't seem to figure out how to do this simple query:

I have an array of values: [1,2,4,5,6,7] and documents like this:

{  "test" : 1 }
{  "test" : 2 }
{  "test" : 3 }

Now I want to query which values are not in any document test property.
I've tried to use $setDifference like so:
 db.testDocs.aggregate([{$project:{test:1, notInList: { $setDifference: [[1,2,3,4,5,6], "$id"]}, _id:0}}])

but this is obviously incorrect. In fact I'm not even sure if $setDifference is the best way to do query like this. If it is then how to make it work? If it isn't then whats the best way?

Oh, and the query is actually on over 100 000 values but I just simplified the situation for this question.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to do this query but this is how I solved it:

```
db.testDocs.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group:
                {
                    "_id":null,
                    values:
                    {
                        $push: "$test"
                    }
                }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                difference: {
                    $setDifference: [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], "$values"]
                }
            }
        }
])
```

Quite simple actually. I just didn't know how to use the aggregate framework properly.